# Pass data from Android code to Javascript method loaded from an external URL?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am creating an app where i use a WebView this is how the code loks like in the 
onCreate method

[image: OnCreate method in the Main Activity]

On that Default.aspx page i have a button from which i call an android method . Below is the code for the Javascript interface and then the HTML for the button which calles this method.

[image: Adding the javascript interface to the web view]

And below is the HTML code where onclick of the button the WebInterface classes method "doEchoTest" will be called.
[image: HTML where the Android call is being made..]

In the doEchoTest method i call the mAppView.loadUrl() with the javascript calling the method in the aspx page that is the method "**returnNow**"

[image: WebInterface class method which contains the "doEchoTest"]

This javascript method never gets called ,Now i know one reason is because this webview.loadUrl() method contains an URL which is not from the assets folder ????

Is there any way i could achive the above ??? That is webView.loadUrl loading an external url that is with http://something ..... . Is there any way i could pass data to this page upon calling of this android java method  "doSomeTest" ??

Thanks in advance ,

Francis P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that a javascript alert will do anything without a [WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) attached, could be wrong though. It may be the returnNow function is being called, its just not doing anything.

You can pass data to the url by using GET request parameters ?param=value&param2=value

Comment: Thanks !! I tried by adding a span and displaying the returned data from the Android code .. Simply Worked !!!! ;) Thanks a lot !!!